# Unable to run migration after configure DeviseSamlAuthenticatable rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, saml

I'm trying to config SAML with Devise for allow users register on a platform with data already have on other platform. For that i'm trying to use the gem DeviseSamlAuthenticatable for that.
https://github.com/onemedical/devise_saml_authenticatable

When i try to run a migration, console says that:

...gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:428:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the`:as`option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with`resources` as explained here:

Following the instructions for the Gem, i done the following.

On **User.rb model** added:

```
:saml_authenticatable, :trackable
```

And then looks like this:

```
devise :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :database_authenticatable,
         :saml_authenticatable, :trackable
```

On  **config/initializers/devise.rb** added (sample instructions code)

```
Devise.setup do |config|
    ...
    # ==> Configuration for :saml_authenticatable

    # Create user if the user does not exist. (Default is false)
    config.saml_create_user = true

    # Update the attributes of the user after a successful login. (Default is false)
    config.saml_update_user = true

    # Set the default user key. The user will be looked up by this key. Make
    # sure that the Authentication Response includes the attribute.
    config.saml_default_user_key = :email

    # Optional. This stores the session index defined by the IDP during login.  If provided it will be used as a salt
    # for the user's session to facilitate an IDP initiated logout request.
    config.saml_session_index_key = :session_index

    # You can set this value to use Subject or SAML assertation as info to which email will be compared
    # If you don't set it then email will be extracted from SAML assertation attributes
    config.saml_use_subject = true

    # You can support multiple IdPs by setting this value to a class that implements a #settings method which takes
    # an IdP entity id as an argument and returns a hash of idp settings for the corresponding IdP.
    config.idp_settings_adapter = nil

    # You provide you own method to find the idp_entity_id in a SAML message in the case of multiple IdPs
    # by setting this to a custom reader class, or use the default.
    # config.idp_entity_id_reader = DeviseSamlAuthenticatable::DefaultIdpEntityIdReader

    # You can set a handler object that takes the response for a failed SAML request and the strategy,
    # and implements a #handle method. This method can then redirect the user, return error messages, etc.
    # config.saml_failed_callback = nil

    # Configure with your SAML settings (see [ruby-saml][] for more information).
    config.saml_configure do |settings|
      settings.assertion_consumer_service_url     = "http://localhost:3000/users/saml/auth"
      settings.assertion_consumer_service_binding = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
      settings.name_identifier_format             = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"
      settings.issuer                             = "http://localhost:3000/saml/metadata"
      settings.authn_context                      = ""
      settings.idp_slo_target_url                 = "http://localhost/simplesaml/www/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php"
      settings.idp_sso_target_url                 = "http://localhost/simplesaml/www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php"
      settings.idp_cert                           = <<-CERT.chomp
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111_______IDP_CERTIFICATE________111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
      CERT
    end
  end
```

And on **config/attribute-map.yml** added (same sample)

```
  "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:uid": "user_name"
  "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:email": "email"
  "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:name": "last_name"
  "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:givenName": "name"
```

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in an issue on the repository: https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable/issues/83

Since this model is authenticatable with both database authentication and SAML, you need to fully configure both strategies, including routes. This is a requirement of devise and is not really obvious.

Check out this wiki page I recently added to document the details a bit more clearly: https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable/wiki/Supporting-multiple-authentication-strategies